# How to set GOROOT when installing via Brew?

Tags: go, homebrew

I installed Go with the following command:

`brew install go`

It is now installed under `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.19.2`

I than set the variables like so:

```
export GOROOT=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.19.2/bin/go/libexec
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

When I try `go env` I get this:

`go: cannot find GOROOT directory: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.19.2/bin/go/libexec`

**What is the mistake here?**

Comment: Do not set GOROOT.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I works when I don't set it. `go env` show me everything and `GOROOT` shows the same path as in my question. Some magic I don't understand. Please provide an answer and I'll happily accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some fixes:

- `export GOROOT="$(brew --prefix golang)/libexec"`
- Do not set GOROOT
- Use [official installer](https://go.dev/dl/) instead of brew (recommended).

Comment: Could you expand on why official installer is recommended over Brew? I find brew convenient since it makes simple upgrades to new versions, but I don't know if I'm missing something with the official installer.